# 内部クラスの template 関数が解決されない

Tags: c++, templates

以下の C++ ソースコードにおいて

```
template<typename _t_type_>
class OuterClass {
public:
    class InnerClass;
};

template<typename _t_type_>
class OuterClass<_t_type_>::InnerClass
{
public:
    InnerClass() { }

    template<typename _t_type2_>
    InnerClass(const typename OuterClass<_t_type2_>::InnerClass& _a_InnerClass_) {  }
};

struct foo { };
struct bar { };

int main()
{
    OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass o1;
    OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass o2 = o1; // error: no viable conversion from 'OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass' to 'OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass'
}
```

`OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass o2 = o1;` がエラーとなります。

```
    template<typename _t_type2_>
    InnerClass(const typename OuterClass<_t_type2_>::InnerClass& _a_InnerClass_) {  }
```

において `_t_type_` が `bar`, `_t_type2_` が `foo` となって解決されることを期待したのですが、期待通りではありませんでした。 clang++, g++ の両方でコンパイルしたのですが同じ結果でした。

やりたいことは任意の `typename T` に対し

```
    OuterClass<T>::InnerClass
```

となって、 任意の `typename　T1` と任意の `typename T2` で

```
    OuterClass<T1>::InnerClass　と　OuterClass<T2>::InnerClass
```

のコピーコンストラクタが成り立つようにしたいためです。

- **質問1**: なぜこれは解決できないでエラーとなるのでしょうか。
- **質問2**: エラーがでないようにするには、どうしたらいいでしょうか。

参考までに

```
    OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass o2 = o1
```

をコメントアウトすることで、 `InnerClass() { }` は期待どおりに機能します。

Comment: `template <typename U> InnerClass(const U&)`なら通せますが、そういう話ではないですよね。`InnerClass`同士に制限したいというのが真意でしょうか？

Comment: InnerClass同士に制限したいというのが真意です。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 質問2： エラーがでないようにするには、どうしたらいいでしょうか。
>   コメントより： InnerClass同士に制限したい

「`OuterClass<??>::InterClass`同士のみ相互代入を許容する」という目的であれば、下記コードのように"マーカー"(`magic_type_for_innerclass`)を用意することで実現可能です。関数テンプレートへのデフォルト引数を使っているため、C++11以降が必要です。

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename _t_type_>
class OuterClass {
public:
    class InnerClass;
};

template<typename _t_type_>
class OuterClass<_t_type_>::InnerClass
{
public:
    typedef void magic_type_for_innerclass;
    InnerClass() { }

    // コンストラクタ
    template<
        typename U,
        typename = typename U::magic_type_for_innerclass
    >
    InnerClass(const U& rhs) {  }

    // 代入演算子
    template<
        typename U,
        typename = typename U::magic_type_for_innerclass
    >
    InnerClass& operator=(const U& rhs) { return *this; }
};

struct foo { };
struct bar { };

int main()
{
    OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass o1;
    OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass o2 = o1;
    o1 = o2;

//  無関係なクラス間代入はエラー
//  OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass o3 = foo{};
//  o3 = foo{};
}
```

おまけ：[テンプレート関数ではコピーコンストラクタ／代入演算子とならない](http://cpplover.blogspot.jp/2011/07/blog-post_24.html)ため、ここではコピー"風"コンストラクタ／代入演算子という感じになりますね。

---

> 質問１：　なぜこれは解決できないでエラーとなるのでしょうか。

感覚的な説明では「OuterクラスとInnerクラス同士では直接的な関係をもっていないため、Innerクラス実引数からOuterクラスを推論することは不可能」くらいでしょ‌​うか。

<del>厳密な説明では、C++11言語仕様の§14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type] / Paragraph 8 で実引数から型推論のパターン列挙していますが、ここで`Outer<T>::Inner`からテンプレート型パラメータ`T`を推論するルールが定義されないため。となる気がします（正直、自信はありません…）。</del>

このコンパイラ動作の根拠（C++言語仕様）は、「Outerクラス部分はテンプレート型推論の対象外となるから」という理由のようです。（thanks to @MitsuruKariya さんコメント）

質問コードに適用すると *qualified-id*＝`OuterClass<T>::InnerClass`、*nested-name-specifier*＝`OuterClass<T>::`となり、テンプレート型パラメータ`T`はnon-deduced contextsにあるため、型推論が行われないという結果となります。簡単には「最終`::`の右側でしか型推論されない」とみなせばOKです。

C++11言語仕様§14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type] / Paragraph 5より引用：

> 5 The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - The *nested-name-specifier* of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*.
> - [...]

Comment: やりたいことはできています。素晴らしい。ありがとうございます。

Comment: がこれってoperator=には通用しないですよね。

質問に明示していなかったのですが、operator=でも同様の制約を付けたいのですが（すみません後出しで)

そもそも、なんで template<typename U> InnerClass(const OuterClass<U>::InnerClass)が無視されるのかが謎です。

Comment: 「Innerクラス実引数からOuterクラスを推論することは不可能」なるほどです。operator=もふくめてありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決されない理由は、親クラスが non-deduced contexts(推論しない文脈)だからではないでしょうか。C++11 仕様の§14.8.2.5[temp.deduct.type]/p.5 に列挙されている「推論しない文脈」の1番目に "The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id." とあります。これからすると、:: から左側は一切推論対象外のようです。推論対象外としている理由までは書かれていませんが・・・

Answer (score 4):

代替案は既に他の方が回答していますので脇に置きつつ。
ISO/IEC 14882:2014 を見直していたら、以下の記述を見付けました。
テンプレート引数の推論のコンテキストに現れないテンプレート引数は推論の対象とならない、ということで例が挙げられています。
この記述は、14882:2003, 14882:2014にも同様に存在します。

14.8.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type p16 の Note:

> [ Note: Template parameters do not participate in template argument deduction
>   if they are used only in non-deduced contexts. For example,
>
> ```c++
> template<int i, typename T>
> T deduce(typename A<T>::X x, // T is not deduced here
>   T t, // but T is deduced here
>   typename B<i>::Y y); // i is not deduced here
> A<int> a;
> B<77> b;
> int x = deduce<77>(a.xm, 62, b.ym);
> // T is deduced to be int, a.xm must be convertible to
> // A<int>::X
> // i is explicitly specified to be 77, b.ym must be convertible
> // to B<77>::Y
> ```
>
> —end note ]

この例の `deduce` の第一引数 `typename A<T>::X x` が正に今回の例に当たると思います。
これが推論対象ではないのは、既出ですが、 14.8.2.5 p8 で例示されているいずれのパターンにも属さないからでしょうかね。正確なところはちょっと自信がありません。

蛇足かもしれませんが、 14.8.2.5 p8 で、型推論できるパターンの列挙部を引用します。
ここで、Tはテンプレートの型引数、TTはテンプレートのテンプレート型引数、iは型ではないテンプレート引数を表します。

> T
>   *cv-list* T
>   T*
>   T&
>   T&&
>   T[*integer-constant* ]
>   *template-name* <T> (where template-name refers to a class template)
>   *type* (T)
>   T()
>   T(T)
>   T *type* ::*
>   type T::*
>   T T::*
>   T (*type* ::* )()
>   *type* (T::* )()
>   *type* (*type* ::* )(T)
>   *type* (T::*)(T)
>   T (*type* ::* )(T)
>   T (T::* )()
>   T (T::* )(T)
>   *type* [i]
>   *template-name* <i> (where *template-name* refers to a class template)
>   TT<T>
>   TT<i>
>   TT<>

*template-name* <T> まではありますが、typename *template-name* <T>::*type* はないようです。
引用元は 14882:2014で、2011も同じ。2003は右辺値参照がないことと、関数型がポインタになっている違いがありました。

Comment: これは勉強になりました。ありがとう御座います

Answer (score 2):

templateクラスの場合、template引数が違うクラスは、別クラス扱いになってしまうためです。つまり、`OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass`に`OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass`を代入しようとするのは、

```
class OuterFoo{
    class Inner{
    };
};
class OuterBar{
    class Inner{
    };
};
```

と定義されている場合に、`OuterFoo::Inner`に`OuterBar::Inner`を代入しようとしているのと同じことです。

InnerClassがtemplate引数に非依存なのであれば、外部クラスとしてしまってはどうでしょうか？
（01/27 11:13 コードを間違えていたので、修正）

```
class OutOfInnerClass{
    OutOfInnerClass(OutOfInnerClass& _a_InnerClass_) {  }
};
template<typename _t_type_>
class OuterClass {
public:
    typedef OutOfInnerClass InnerClass;
};

template<typename _t_type_>
class OuterClass<_t_type_>::InnerClass
{
public:
    typedef OutOfInnerClass InnerClass;
};

struct foo { };
struct bar { };

int main()
{
    OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass o1;
    OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass o2 = o1;

}
```

Comment: 外部クラスではなく内部クラスで実現したいです。
参考までにInnerClassを外部クラスにすると期待通りにります

Answer (score 2):

ネストしている型はテンプレートの解決時に推論できないことがあります。例えば、上記のコードに、以下のコードが続いていると考えてください。

```
struct baz {};

template<>
class OuterClass<baz> {
public:
    typedef OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass InnerClass;
};
```

この場合、`OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass`と`OuterClass<baz>::InnerClass`は同じ型になりますので、`InnerClass`のテンプレートコピーコンストラクタが呼び出された時に、`_t_type2_`を`foo`と解決すべきか`baz`と解決すべきかコンパイラには判断できません。

このため、提示されたコードはコンパイルできないのです。解決方法は、何をしたいかによって異なると思います。

追記:
以下の様なコードでは、`_t_type2_`は、`foo`になるべきでしょうか。それとも`baz`になるべきでしょうか。

```
OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass o1;
const OuterClass<baz>::InnerClass& o3 = o1;
OuterClass<bar>::InnerClass o2 = o3;
```

Comment: _t_type2_をfooと解決すべきかbazと解決すべきかコンパイラには判断できません。　←理解したような。。　ありがとう御座います。

Comment: しかしよくよく考えると、o1はOuterClass<foo>::InnerClass なので
_t_type2_ = foo　となりそうなものですが

Comment: 字面は違っても同じ型なので、コンパイラは区別できないのです。ちょっと例を追加しました。

Answer (score 0):

基底クラスからの継承ではダメなんですか？
このようなクラス設計にしなければならない理由を知りたいです。

```
class ParentClass{
public:
    ParentClass(){}
};

template<typename T>
class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
public:
    ChildClass(){}
    ChildClass(const ParentClass &parentClass){}
};

struct foo { };
struct bar { };

int main(void)
{
    ChildClass<foo> i1;
    ChildClass<bar> i2 = i1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OuterClass<foo>::InnerClass　という使い方をしたいためです。